# jquery dynamic position change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this jquery color picker plugin http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/ in my web application. I need to do some design tweaks. I'm gonna show some sample features on the application. Please look at this http://jsfiddle.net/FSDPH/8/ there is a movable box with accordions. In the color section, I've implemented that color picker plugin which I can't show in the jsfiddle. What I need is, when the color picker is selected and if the **box** is moved beyond the (document) section, the **box** and **color picker palette** should dynamically change its position inside the document area. I've succeeded in dynamically changing the box position but I can't make it work for the color picker palette.

Here is the jquery code: (for dymanically altering the box and colorpicker palette position)

```
var dwidth = $(document).width() - 225; // #box_bg width
$("#box_bg").draggable({
stop: function(event, ui) {
      var npos = $("#box_bg").position();
      if ( npos.left > dwidth)
      {
          $(".colorpicker").css("left","-133px!important");
          $("#box_bg").css("left", dwidth+"px");
      }
      } 
});
```

In the above code, $("#box_bg") is working when the box is moved beyond the document area. But it is not working for $(".colorpicker") the **left** property is not changing in the colorpicker.css file. Why is it so?

**UPDATE**

Here I've shown more clearly, please check this out :)

http://jsfiddle.net/rkumarnirmal/4GrsD/3/

Could anyone guide me?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to change the the left property of .colorpicker in the css file? Your code is trying to change all of the .colorpicker elements' css left property.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to change left property of .colorpicker

Comment: I could'nt get you. The .colorpicker class is used only once in my html file. I checked it

Comment: It contains images. so i can't able to add in jsfiddle

Comment: You said "the left property is not changing in the colorpicker.css file", so it seems like your are trying to change the css file, not the element style. Without instantiating the colorpicker, you can't change its style properties.

Comment: Check out the updated section

Answer (score 0):

The left property of the colorpicker is calculated in the plugin every it is shown. Until you change the plugin, the left property will always be calculated on the fly.

Here is the code from the plugin:

```
show = function (ev) {
    var cal = $('#' + $(this).data('colorpickerId'));
    cal.data('colorpicker').onBeforeShow.apply(this, [cal.get(0)]);
    var pos = $(this).offset();
    var viewPort = getViewport();
    var top = pos.top + this.offsetHeight;
    var left = pos.left;
    if (top + 176 > viewPort.t + viewPort.h) {
        top -= this.offsetHeight + 176;
    }
    if (left + 356 > viewPort.l + viewPort.w) {
        left -= 356;
    }
    cal.css({left: left + 'px', top: top + 'px'});
    if (cal.data('colorpicker').onShow.apply(this, [cal.get(0)]) != false) {
        cal.show();
    }
    $(document).bind('mousedown', {cal: cal}, hide);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've actually done some mistake. I used left: 85px!important where **!important** is blocking my code feature. I removed and its working now :)